# Is the result of your training session random, or related to something the user controls?

Tags: magikarp-jump

When training in Magikarp Jump, you can have either a "Good" (1x), "Great" (2x), or "Excellent" (3x?) result.  I've noticed that I seem to have more "Great" or "Excellent" results on certain trainings - the tree knockdown one in particular - and nearly none on some, like the sandbag which I've never had a non-good result (out of, maybe, 20 tries); on the other hand, my son has had plenty of sandbag bust-ups.

Is this random chance, or is the 'tapping' or something else I'm doing having an effect on the result?

Comment: And yes, I realize that the N size here is very small, hence the question, since I can't really get good statistics on this myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [serebii.net](https://www.serebii.net/magikarpjump/training.shtml), "There are also three different tiers of results for each training regime, each giving higher Jump Power values of double or triple the base value, **but this is selected at random** so you have little control."

I can attest to this. Sometimes I can get 2 "Amazing" ratings in a row and then not get them again for a while. The rating system is likely based on a percent chance per tier but there is no information on what the chance of each tier is.

Comment: Having seen no better information to this point I will accept this unless/until someone proves differently.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: I got an "Awesome" training once when I was Trainer level 3, then did not get another one until Trainer level 17. Once I did get one, I got "Awesome" training four (!) times in a row. Haven't seen it since though.